# How to style an A element inside a parent class or id

Tags: css

I'm trying different ways but cannot style a text color for a specific  element which is a child of a parent element

with a class and an ID.

```
<li id="menu-item-849" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-849"><a href="https://mywebsite.com/">You won’t want to miss it!</a></li>
<a href="https://myerbsite.com/">You won’t want to miss it!</a>
<li id="menu-item-849" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-849"><a href="https://mywebsite.com/">You won’t want to miss it!</a></li>
```

I would like to color the text red in the  tag
so I'm trying to target the ID:

```
#menu-item-849 .a {
color: red important;
}
```

or target the class:

```
li#menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-849 a {
color: red important;
}
```

I'm doing something wrong for sure, somebody here can help?
Thanks

Comment: `color: red important` --> `color: red!important`

Comment: corrected but not the problem

Comment: Thank you, this is working:
#menu-item-849 > a {
color: red;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, on the first you're looking for a child link element with the class of `a`. Try

```
#menu-item-849 > a {
color: red;
}
```

Or if you want to go for the class,

```
.menu-item > a {
color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is wrong. Id selector starts with `#`, class selector starts with `.` and element selector is the name of the element itself.
So do either this

```
#menu-item-849 a {
    color: red;
}
```

or preferabale this class selector

```
.menu-item-849 a {
    color: red;
}
```

Try to not use `important` because it makes it hard to overwrite the styles at another place.
Don't give the same `id` to multiple elements, this is invalid. Use class names instead.